# How to create custom dialog with cardview in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-alertdialog

I want to create a custom dialog in my app with the cardview. Searched on Google and implemented the same but did not got the expected result. So can anyone help me out in implementing it.

The result which i am getting

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zpoS.png)

This is my **category.xml** file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="3dip" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:text="Choose Categories"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

and this is my **custom.xml** file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/categoryText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="safsafsa"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    />
```

And this is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final int CATEGORY_ID =0;
private Context mContext;
Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            showDialog(CATEGORY_ID);
        }
    });
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id) {

        case CATEGORY_ID:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            Context mContext = this;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
            GridView gridview = (GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(arg1.getContext(), "Position is "+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            ImageView close = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setView(layout);
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

And this is my **ImageAdapter.java**

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
            mContext = c;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled,
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
                convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryText);
                holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.icon.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            holder.title.setText(categoryContent[position]);
            holder.icon.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            TextView title;
            ImageView icon;
        }
        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp,R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp,R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp
        };

    }
    private String[] categoryContent = {
            "Pubs", "Restuarants","shopping",
            "theatre","train", "taxi",
    };


}
```

Comment: parent layout should be cardview in custom row instead of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your custom.xml into this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="safsafsa" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and a background like this into gridview

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

Comment: Yes this i know..initially i tried to do it without cardview. For that only i am not getting the result

Comment: tried adding the backgrouned still i am getting a dialog with some doted images

Comment: i have added the result which i am getting please check

Comment: about which layout your telling

Comment: TextView whose id is categoryText

Answer (score 2):

You should use this

```java
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dialog fragment and set the background drawable as **TRANSPARENT**

```
val dialog = context?.let { Dialog(it) }
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
//For Not title bar
dialog?.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
// Include dialog.xml file
dialog?.setContentView(R.layout.dailog_confirm_tab)
 dialog?.show()
dialog?.btnConfirm?.setOnClickListener { // Close dialog
        dialog.dismiss()
        //Perform logic actions
    }
```